# Using global new with a custom memory manager

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management, syntax, new-operator

I have written a custom memory manager and am having trouble trying to hide it behind the scenes. It's API exposes a template method Allocate which takes no parameters. This is how the magic is done. It uses the type provided to deduce some things and make sure it can call the destructor later, so it is very important that I am able to get the RTTI during this method.

The problem is that I want to use the global new so the memory manager is behind the scenes and it doesn't impose strange syntax (and if I use global new I will also be able to managed anything, not just user code).

So the question is: is there some way I can hide the call to `Allocate<Object>( )` within `operator new`?

Answer (score 0):

You can overload `operator new()` and `operator delete()` for individual classes. Within each of these operator you would know the base type of the object being allocated or deallocated. If you further make sure that each of the derived types does overload these operators you'd know the exact type. I don't think there is a way to determine the type if objects being allocated/deallocated otherwise.

Note that these operator are called when there is no object around, either because it wasn't constructed, yet, or because it was already destructed.

Comment: That would be an option, but my goal is to have this system just "turned on" and work for everything, including outside libraries I/the user may not have access to. So this doesn't solve my problem. Thanks, though.